# I need to filter a list, that I get with a context

Tags: react-hooks, server-side-rendering, react-context, next.js13

I'm newer in nextjs 13 and I need to filter a list but I alwais get into a inifinitive loop

My context:

```
"use client";

import { createContext, useContext } from "react";

const MyContext = createContext([]);

export const ContextProvider = ({ children, listFromApi }) => {
  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={listFromApi}>
      {children}
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useMyContext = () => {
  const listFromApi = useContext(MyContext);

  if (!listFromApi) {
    return [];
  }
  return listFromApi;
};

export default MyContext;
```

where I use the provider:

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { ContextProvider } from "./contexts/Context";
import getInfoFromApi from "./api/getInfoFromApi";

export default async function RootLayout({ children }) {

  const listFromApi = await getInfoFromApi()

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <nav>
          <Link href={"/"}  title="Go to home">
            Home
          </Link>
        </nav>
        <hr className="separator" />
          <ContextProvider listFromApi={listFromApi}>{children}</ContextProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

And I use the context here,

```
'use client'

export default async function Main() {
  const listFromApi = useMyContext()
 const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const listToRender = listFromApi.filter((x) =>{
    return x.title.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())

  });
  return (
      <>
        <input
            id="search"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Filter"
            onChange={(ev)=>setValue(ev.target.value)}
          />
        <List list={listToRender} />
      </>
  );
}
```

I'd tried to put into the localStorage and filter with that data, but does not work

```
const [listFiltered, setListFiltered] = useState([]);
let listFromApi = useMyContext()
let nowDate = Date.now();
let dateLs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("date"));
if(dateLs && nowDate - dateLs > 86400000){
  localStorage.setItem("date", JSON.stringify(nowDate));
  localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(listFromApi));
  setListFiltered(listFromApi);
}else{
  listFromApi = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("list"));
  setListFiltered(listFromApi);

}
```

Also I tried to put into a useEffect but also doesn't work... And I don't know what happens

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that, since you haven't updated the value of your state variable `value`, you're trying to get elements of `listFromApi` which contain an empty string, of course they do, all of them.

I don't know what `value` represents but for debugging purposes, try setting initial state (`value`) to something different from an empty string.

Something like:
`const [value, setValue] = seState("default")`.

If it works, you should then set the default value of you state variable `value` to whatever suits your needs.

Good luck